# Heroku FlywayException: Unable to autodetect JDBC driver for url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku, flyway, heroku-postgres

I've tried to deploy my app to Heroku. I can see that logs have exception like:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to autodetect JDBC driver for url: jdbc:postgres://hostname:5432/databaseName`.

I know why I have that exception because of **jdbc:postgres**://... in url. Flyway expects url like this: **jdbc:postgresql**://.... to define driver. But Heroku provides database url without suffix **ql**. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I was a little bit confusing when I saw this url which was provided by heroku.

```
postgres://host_name:5432/database_name
```

But I just changed it to

```
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:5432/${DB_NAME}
```

Before it I had

```
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:${DATABASE_URL} => postgres://host_name:5432/database_name
```

I just replace **postgres** to **postgresql** finaly now I have no problem with flyway.